# show this statement is a tautology using conditional statements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

Have been doing some homework questions and got stuck on this question

$$(p ∨ q) ∧ (p → r) ∧ (q → r) → r $$

I got it simplified to

$$((¬p ∧ ¬q) ∨ ¬r ∧ (p ∨ q)) ∨ r$$

but now i'm not sure what to do now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Don't know how to use the  MathJax formatting for the formulas yet so I typed the statement this way.

Comment: And it was precisely because I assumed that you don't know how to use MathJax that I provided a few links to webpages from which you can learn it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Implication Equivalence is typically known as $p \to q = \neg p \lor q$, but note that that means that $\neg (p \to q) = \neg(\neg p \lor q) = \neg \neg p \land \neg q = p \land \neg q$

So, let's use the $\neg (p \to q) =p \land \neg q$ principle (which some texbooks actually have as an implicit part of the Implication equivalence).

Then:

$$[(p ∨ q) ∧ (p → r) ∧ (q → r)] → r =$$

$$\neg \neg ([(p \lor q) \land (\neg p \lor r) \land (\neg q \lor r)] \to r) =$$

$$\neg ((p \lor q) \land (\neg p \lor r) \land (\neg q \lor r) \land \neg r) $$

OK, now use:

**Reduction**

$p \land (\neg p \lor q) = p \land q$ (in the context of $p$, the $\neg p \lor q$ term 'reduces to just $q$)

Applied to where we were:

$$\neg ((p \lor q) \land (\neg p \lor r) \land (\neg q \lor r) \land \neg r) =$$

$$\neg ((p \lor q) \land \neg p \land \neg q  \land \neg r) =$$

$$\neg (q \land \neg p \land \neg q  \land \neg r) =$$

$$\neg (\bot) = \top$$

Comment: Thanks, didn't know I could use Implication equivalence like that.

Comment: @TheDasher Well, like I said, some texbooks have it .. but others don't. But I showed you how to derive it if you don't so you can always insert those steps if needed. Glad I could help :)